# How to map a single entity from a list to a field in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm running into a problem using hibernate to map a versioned entity to a single property.

I have a table a:

```
id(long)
referenceIdentifier(uuid)
isLatestversion(boolean)
```

and a table b:

```
id(long)
someArbitraryAttachedInfo(String)
referenceToTableA(uuid)
```

Table a will have multiple versons of the same object, different id's but the referenceIdentifier remains the same. There is only one object a with the isLatestversion flag set to true for any given referenceIdentifier (We will determine the latest version from a revision log).
We want table b to have the uuid so we can set it once and not have to track and update whenever a newer version of a is availabe and to see all relevant attachments when viewing an older version.

How can I model this in hibernate?
When I use a @ManyToOne with a @JoinColumn and @Where it generates an unique-constraint on table a's uuid.
When i use @JoinFormula it generates a bytea field instead of the referenced column's type.

Thank you for any help or pointers you can provide.